# VideoView crashing after few hours of playing videos, says frames skipped in logs and can't play this video popup on screen Android?

Tags: android, android-videoview

Android VideoView works for few hours and plays videos, but after a few hours it crashes and says can't play this video. also in logs it show skipped 100 frames or so and the video never plays, I am attaching the logs, is this info enough to clear the problem ?

```
04-21 11:10:07.465 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: stop called in state 0
04-21 11:10:07.465 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: message received msg=100, ext1=-38, ext2=0
04-21 11:10:07.465 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: error (-38, 0)
04-21 11:10:07.465 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: callback application
04-21 11:10:07.465 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: back from callback
04-21 11:10:07.465 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: setListener
04-21 11:10:07.465 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: disconnect
04-21 11:10:08.575 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: isPlayingVideo
04-21 11:10:08.575 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: destructor
04-21 11:10:08.575 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: disconnect
04-21 11:10:08.575 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: isPlayingVideo
04-21 11:10:08.585 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: constructor
04-21 11:10:08.585 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: setListener
04-21 11:10:08.585 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: setDataSource(59, 7752196, 2156535)
04-21 11:10:08.685 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: Unable to to create media player
04-21 11:10:08.685 16564-16564/com.example.android D/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
04-21 11:10:08.685 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: setDataSource(android.resource://com.example.android/2131165185)
04-21 11:10:08.685 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: setVideoSurfaceTexture
04-21 11:10:08.695 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: MediaPlayer::setAudioStreamType
04-21 11:10:08.695 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: setVideoSurfaceTexture
04-21 11:10:08.695 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: prepareAsync
04-21 11:10:08.695 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: prepareAsync_l
04-21 11:10:08.695 16564-16578/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: message received msg=100, ext1=1, ext2=1
04-21 11:10:08.695 16564-16578/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: error (1, 1)
04-21 11:10:08.695 16564-16578/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: callback application
04-21 11:10:08.695 16564-16578/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: back from callback
04-21 11:10:08.695 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: constructor
04-21 11:10:08.695 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: setListener
04-21 11:10:08.695 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: setDataSource(59, 27668376, 9138324)
04-21 11:10:08.805 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: Unable to to create media player
04-21 11:10:08.805 16564-16564/com.example.android D/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
04-21 11:10:08.805 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: setDataSource(android.resource://com.example.android/2131165673)
04-21 11:10:08.805 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: setVideoSurfaceTexture
04-21 11:10:08.805 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: MediaPlayer::setAudioStreamType
04-21 11:10:08.805 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: setVideoSurfaceTexture
04-21 11:10:08.805 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: prepareAsync
04-21 11:10:08.805 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: prepareAsync_l
04-21 11:10:08.805 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: stop
04-21 11:10:08.805 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: stop called in state 0
04-21 11:10:08.805 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: message received msg=100, ext1=-38, ext2=0
04-21 11:10:08.805 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: error (-38, 0)
04-21 11:10:08.805 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: callback application
04-21 11:10:08.805 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: back from callback
04-21 11:10:08.805 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: setListener
04-21 11:10:08.805 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: disconnect
04-21 11:10:08.805 16564-26579/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: message received msg=100, ext1=1, ext2=1
04-21 11:10:08.805 16564-26579/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: error (1, 1)
04-21 11:10:08.805 16564-26579/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: callback application
04-21 11:10:08.805 16564-26579/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: back from callback
04-21 11:10:09.925 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: isPlayingVideo
04-21 11:10:09.925 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: destructor
04-21 11:10:09.925 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: disconnect
04-21 11:10:09.925 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: isPlayingVideo
04-21 11:10:09.935 16564-16564/com.example.android I/Choreographer: Skipped 118 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-21 11:10:09.965 16564-16564/com.example.android W/MediaPlayer: mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
04-21 11:10:09.965 16564-16564/com.example.android W/MediaPlayer: mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
04-21 11:10:09.965 16564-16564/com.example.android W/MediaPlayer: mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
04-21 11:10:09.965 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,1)
04-21 11:10:09.965 16564-16564/com.example.android D/VideoView: Error: 1,1
04-21 11:10:10.025 16564-16564/com.example.android D/Pending Task: Event Started
04-21 11:10:10.025 16564-16564/com.example.android I/System.out: true wifi
04-21 11:10:10.025 16564-16564/com.example.android D/Pending Tasks: 0
04-21 11:10:10.025 16564-16564/com.example.android D/Pending Task: Total Tasks 0
04-21 11:10:11.795 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: stop
04-21 11:10:11.795 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: stop called in state 0
04-21 11:10:11.795 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: message received msg=100, ext1=-38, ext2=0
04-21 11:10:11.795 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: error (-38, 0)
04-21 11:10:11.795 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: callback application
04-21 11:10:11.795 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: back from callback
04-21 11:10:11.795 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: setListener
04-21 11:10:11.795 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: disconnect
04-21 11:10:11.845 16564-19354/com.example.android I/ArduinoCommsActivity: Received : <FP_STATUS_S> length: 11
04-21 11:10:11.845 16564-19354/com.example.android I/ArduinoCommsActivity: Received : <T:ID;T1:25.00;T2:25.00;E1:15;E2:12;TL:608482;TL> length: 47
                                                                                                       > length: 31
04-21 11:10:12.905 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: isPlayingVideo
04-21 11:10:12.905 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: destructor
04-21 11:10:12.905 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: disconnect
04-21 11:10:12.905 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: isPlayingVideo
04-21 11:10:12.905 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: constructor
04-21 11:10:12.905 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: setListener
04-21 11:10:12.905 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: setDataSource(59, 7752196, 2156535)
04-21 11:10:13.005 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: Unable to to create media player
04-21 11:10:13.005 16564-16564/com.example.android D/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
04-21 11:10:13.005 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: setDataSource(android.resource://com.example.android/2131165185)
04-21 11:10:13.015 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: setVideoSurfaceTexture
04-21 11:10:13.015 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: MediaPlayer::setAudioStreamType
04-21 11:10:13.015 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: setVideoSurfaceTexture
04-21 11:10:13.015 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: prepareAsync
04-21 11:10:13.015 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: prepareAsync_l
04-21 11:10:13.015 16564-17157/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: message received msg=100, ext1=1, ext2=1
04-21 11:10:13.015 16564-17157/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: error (1, 1)
04-21 11:10:13.015 16564-17157/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: callback application
04-21 11:10:13.015 16564-17157/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: back from callback
04-21 11:10:13.015 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: constructor
04-21 11:10:13.015 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: setListener
04-21 11:10:13.025 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: setDataSource(59, 12272264, 3763628)
04-21 11:10:13.025 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: setVideoSurfaceTexture
04-21 11:10:13.025 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: MediaPlayer::setAudioStreamType
04-21 11:10:13.025 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: setVideoSurfaceTexture
04-21 11:10:13.025 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: prepareAsync
04-21 11:10:13.025 16564-16564/com.example.android E/MediaPlayer.cpp: prepareAsync_l
```

Comment: are those same files which plays before and one which shows this message?

Comment: yes these are the same files, i've 3 videos in the loop so they're all the same

Comment: from the logs it appears that one of the file is not supported by videoview

Comment: it plays all these files for 3-4 hours and then the problem arises, so am sure they're supported